How to create a query with custom attributes in Laravel Eloquent?
I have a Student model and in database I have a social security number from which I calculate a custom attribute to get the student's age. How can I use it in Eloquent queries?
I have this custom attribute in the model:
public function getAgeAttribute(): int
{
    if (!$this->deleted) {
        $date = substr($this->social_security, 0, 6);
            
        switch (substr($this->social_security, 6, 1)) {                    
            case '-':
                $yy = '19';
                break;
            case 'A':
                $yy = '20';
                break;
            case '+':
                $yy = '18';
                break;
            default:
                return 0;
        }

        $birthday = new \DateTime($yy . substr($date, 4, 2) . '-' . substr($date, 2, 2) . '-' . substr($date, 0, 2));
        $today = new \DateTime('today');

        return $birthday->diff($today)->y;
    }

    return 0;
}

I'm trying to get a count of students between certain ages in controller as follows:
$count = Student::where('deleted', 0)
    ->whereHas('studentSeasons', function($query) {
        $query->whereHas('season', function($query) {
            $query->where('start', '<=', now());
            $query->where('end', '>=', now());
        });
    })
    ->get()
    ->append('age')
    ->where('age', '>=', $request->input('start'))
    ->where('age', '<=', $request->input('end'))
    ->count();

I can append the age to the collection returned by the get() method, but that loads all the student models.
I would like to add the age attribute to the query and only get the count. How can I do this, or can I?

The base query is only for the database, so you cannot use attributes on it. You can only use the attributes on the collection query that you have here.

Thank you for clarification! So I'm doing it the best way possible right now?

the best way would be to make a new field in your students table birthdate and in the migration loop all the student and extract the birthdate from the ssn. then you can simply run the query on that fields. Dont forget to adjust the creation and modification of the student to account for that new field. Without the new field, any other solution would require either the php or the mysql to loop all the students.

I thought about that too but I have over 8000 students and I would have to create the migration and populate the data on production and I don't think it would be worth it. The query as it is now is not that slow. It's just that this is the only query that is not optimized. I'm in a kind of optimization spree right now :-P Thank you for your comments!

@riksae running that on 8000 students will take about 45 seconds.  I think it is worth it.

as @TobyAllen said, it is fast and a one time thing, just consider it like any migration. Dont forget to backup the database before running the migration in production (who knows)

As @aynber said, calculated attributes cant be used in database queries but in your case you can use the field social_security to condition your query.
Here is an example with scopes (add the scopes functions to the Student Class)
$count = Student::where('deleted', 0)
    ->belongsToCurrentSeason() //bonus
    ->ageBetween($request->input('start'), $request->input('end'))
    ->count();

with the scopes:
scopeBelongsToCurrentSeason: use this so you dont have to put those where() everywhere. A scope (and query builders) role is to transform a query into a readable code.
//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
public function scopeBelongsToCurrentSeason(Builder $builder) {
    $builder->whereHas('studentSeasons', function($query) {
        $query->whereHas('season', function($query) {
            $query->where('start', '<=', now());
            $query->where('end', '>=', now());
        });
    });
}

scopeAgeBetween: Here we can use the STR_TO_DATE from mysql and it helps that the date is at the start of the ssn. Here I ignored the 7th character (the one to tell the century) since mysql can auto fill the right century. But if you encounter any issue, use SUBSTR and CASE to build the string to be converted into date.
//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
public function scopeAgeBetween(Builder $builder, $lowAge, $highAge)
{
    $builder->whereRaw(
        "STR_TO_DATE(social_security, '%d%m%y') BETWEEN :start AND :end", 
        [
           ':start' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$lowAge.' year')),
           ':end' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$highAge.' year'))
        ]
    );

}

But I still recommend that you make the extra filed birthdate and populate it in migration (the same migration that adds the field)
Good thing about scopes is that once you add the new field, you just have to update your scope code once and it will work if you dont add required parameters.
